# How to properly handle a variable with the same type as the class it belongs to?

Tags: c++

I am using the two files below for my project. The variable I am referring to, `Node parent`, was originally not a pointer, but I quickly found out this doesn't work for obvious reasons (memory).

So I turned it into a pointer. The problem is that `parent` appears to not be properly handled in my code, so I end up with my application crashing when I execute a function like getParent(). What modifications would fix this problem?

Node.h

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Action.h"
class Node
{
```

Node.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Comment: For performance you should change `std::string title` to `const std::string& title`

Comment: You need to learn how to pass parameters by reference.

Comment: Even better performance `: title(std::move(title))` :) @EdHeal I don't think this gives a performance benefit, the compiler can't move optimize, and instead has to do a copy.

Comment: `std::vector<Node> getChildren();` -- You will be burned by this if your goal is to return the actual children, and not copies of them.  Return a reference if you want the actual children to be returned.

Comment: This code is rife with potential *undefined behavior*. Ex: both the `Node(std::string title, Node parent)` constructor and the `Node::setParent(Node parent)` setter store the address of an automatic temporary variable (the provided parameter) as value of the `this->parent` member. In both cases, the moment the current function exits that object ceases to exist, and the pointer is left dangling. I think you need to study object lifetime, pointers, references, etc. more before taking this on. It isn't as trivial as you may be thinking. Rather the opposite; it's tedious work.

Comment: Also, when copying children you try to set their parent pointer, but what about the grandchildren? Their parents have just moved...

Comment: That does not matter in this particular implementation

Answer (score 1):

You should check if `parent` is `nullptr` or not:

```
bool Node::getParent( Node& node )
{
    if ( parent )
    {
        node = *parent;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to implement the proper copy-constructor of `Node` is needed.
A possible solution is to return the pointer or the reference of the parent node but in several implementation it is dangerous because you allow access directly to an internal member. Decide what is good for you.

Just a suggestion: if you use std::sharer_ptr or std::unique_ptr, some implementation would be much easier.

Comment: Any idea why the parent is not being assigned properly? I added a copy-constructor that carries all the properties over. Its basically a node with a blank string, and no children, parent, actions, etc.

Comment: In getParent(...) method? Are you sure that the `parent` member is not a nullptr? Maybe some code snippet would helpful.

Comment: I think its related to setParent(..) rather than getParent(..), but not sure what could be causing it.

Comment: `void returntoPreviousNode() {
 Node *parent = currentNode.getParent();
 if (parent == nullptr) {
  ; //Do nothing then.
 } else {
  currentNode = *currentNode.getParent();
 }
}`

Comment: For instance this will properly execute currentNode = *currentNode.getParent(); but it will always return a node with an empty title among other empty properties

Answer (score 0):

You should check if parent is null or not before defreferencing.

convert signature of your getParent as:

```
Node* Node::getParent()

Node* Node::getParent() {
    return parent;
}
```

And in your application whenever you access it, check first.

```
Node * parent = getParent();
if(parent==nullptr){
    cout << "parent is null\n";
    raise error;
}else{
    // do whatever you want
}
```